# how do I bind a code line to a value in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How do I bind a value(number) to a specific line in my Code?
For example, If I would change that line because I wrote something else in the code, that number(value) should increase or decrease.

```
as example:
Codeline #5 //Please read the info at code line 22
.....
Codeline #22 //this is info.
```

Let's say I write code between lines 5 and 22 I want to change the Value of 22 in Codeline #5 to make it dynamic. How can I do that? Is my question understandable?

Comment: you can write an extension for that, but you have to label both lines with a unique name, so let the label be enough so search for the `#label_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSCode does not have such a feature implemented. You could either search the [Visual Studio Code Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/) for an extension that does what you need or you'll have to write your own extension for it. I did search for such an extension, but could not find one that would statisfy your needs.

Comment: this is a COMMENT not an answer

Comment: ok. Il take a look at the Visual Studio Code Marketplace.
Thanks for the help =)

Comment: @rioV8 According to [this definition](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297069/15075007), my answer IS an answer.

Comment: @rioV8 well it's not a 100% answer since he didn't provide a complete solution.
However, it still helps me since he said that VSCode doesn't have this implemented.
=)

Comment: @h6h7h8h2 You need some other people to read the VSC docs for you and tell you this or that is not implemented

Comment: @rioV8 sorry I dont understand you're comment.
what do you suggest about my question?